# C++ Windows Credential Provider Error Screen

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

I have developed a custom credential provider for MFA and it is working fine. I am performing my additional authentication checks in GetSerialization() method by calling REST APIs. Now, in case of successful validation through REST API, I am allowing the user to login. But for the case of validation failure, I want to show error screen, like the one default provider shows in case of incorrect username or password (having a button for 'Ok'). I have understood that this is done in ReportResult() by default credential provider in case of logon failure. Can I call ReportResult() to display my custom error message with an 'Ok' button?
Regards,

EDIT: I am doing it like this:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(HRESULT_FROM_NT(ntsStatus)) && SUCCEEDED(HRESULT_FROM_NT(ntsSubstatus)))
{
    SHStrDupW(L"Bad password", ppwszOptionalStatusText);
    *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_ERROR;
}
```

But the screen isn't stopping. It logs in the user. I need to detect the scenario when the windows credentials are correct but the API call fails, so I need to catch that status and display error

Comment: post your code for clarify

Comment: Where are you authenticating using REST API? Are you doing it inside `GetSerialization()`?

Comment: Yes I am doing inside GetSerialization()

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar any advise please?

Comment: @SaileshD I am doing it in GetSerialization(). Can you please assist?

Comment: Have to try `*pcpgsr = CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED;` 
In my use case wih additional `*pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_WARNING;`
 it is enough to display status message.

Comment: @Alexander I am not able to do that. In GetSerialization(), I exactly did as you said, but nothing happens. How are you able to do it?

Comment: I am able to do it now. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you help me with one more thing? On this status message, there is an Ok button, can we change its text from 'Ok' to something else? Also, where can we handle the action on the click of this button?

Comment: @js.hrt You can do nothing with the style of this button except for hide it. The inly action for this button is call of `GetSerialization` method.

Comment: @Alexander Ok. Thanks. While running another custom cp built by someone else, after submitting credentials, I came across a screen that had some text showing the status and a cancel button (demonstrating that the system is working). When I clicked the cancel button, it said "Logon canceled". How can we show this screen to tell the user to wait and give him the option to cancel?

Comment: Inside your `GetSerialisation` you can do almost the same things. Call to `ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents::OnCreatingWindow` method for parents window handle and you can show message box or even create your own dialog window. As you wish you may return `CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED` or `CPGSR_RETURN_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED`.

Comment: @Alexander Yes I have done that, but both of these cases display a separate window. I am talking about a scenario where I have seen an embedded screen with a cancel button (similar to the status screen that has Ok button). Let me check if I can edit and include a screenshot

Comment: @Alexander I have posted it as a new question with a screenshot here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935430/c-windows-credential-provider-progress-screen

Comment: @js-hrt I have been replied to the new post.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you. Your these comments above: "Have to try *pcpgsr = CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED; In my use case wih additional *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_WARNING; it is enough to display status message." helped me to solve the problem. Can you post this as answer so that I can accept?

Comment: @js.hrt I have posted new anwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to try

`*pcpgsr = CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED;`

In my use case wih additional

`*pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_WARNING;`

it is enough to display status message.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportResult(
    NTSTATUS ntsStatus, 
    NTSTATUS ntsSubstatus,
    PWSTR* ppwszOptionalStatusText, 
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON* pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon
    )
```

You can set your own custom message by populating `ppwszOptionalStatusText`. If needed, icon can also be set `pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon` to one of `CPSI_ERROR`,`CPSI_WARNING` or `CPSI_SUCCESS`.

For eg., after checking on `ntsStatus`, you could customize like this

```
SHStrDupW(L"Bad password", ppwszOptionalStatusText);
*pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_ERROR;
```

Edit:

Inside `GetSerialization()`, once the API returns failure, set the `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE` to not finished. Like this

`*pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;`

This should stop the logon to continue.

Edit 2:
As per @js.hrt comment below, to show the status screen from GetSerialization, by using *pcpgsr = CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED; SHStrDupW(L"Bad password", ppwszOptionalStatusText); *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_ERROR; in GetSerialization() without using report result.

Comment: Ok but what I think is ntsStatus is raised by LSA after logon failure (please correct me if wrong). But I need to detect it after failure of my REST API call. Would I have to raise custom ntsStatus and detect it afterwards?

Comment: I am doing it like this:

Comment: I have edited the question and included the code how I am doing

Comment: I have included *pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED; where the API returns failure. Now the logon stops but error is not shown and credential provider is unadvised

Comment: any advise please?

Comment: @js.hrt in my GetSerialization, I am using messageboxes to show api authentication related errors and whenever windows authentication is having issues, using the `ReportResult`. Not sure if we can bypass from `GetSerialization` to directly show status. Tried to find some online documentations related to this and wasn't able to locate one which shows the order in error scenarios.

Comment: I was able to show the status screen by using *pcpgsr = CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED; SHStrDupW(L"Bad password", ppwszOptionalStatusText); *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_ERROR; in GetSerialization() without using report result. Thanks for your help

Comment: There is an Ok button on the status screen. Do you have any idea how can I modify its text? Also, how can I handle what's done on its click?

Comment: @js.hrt edited the answer with your findings in GetSerialization as well, what is it that you want to be done after clicking "OK"?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was thinking of showing this screen as progress status when a task is being performed, and treat this button as a cancel button so that a user can cancel the operation. I saw in another credential provider that a progress screen is displayed with a cancel button, so I though of making that. But i think that is a separate screen

Comment: Yeah, most likely an overlayed screen. If this answer has met the original question's requirements, can you mark this as accepted? Or is there something that is still not answered?

Comment: Yes, original question's requirements are met. Thankyou