# How to add a button to Win Logon Screen

Tags: winlogon

for my enterprise we would want to add a button to the initial windows Logon Screen (or a simple link) that would open a the browser to a specific url we used to reset password using a dedicated web apps.

We pushed a similar solution by CISCO (CISCO GINA) a few time ago.

But it is unclear for me GINA is deprecated in Win10 and Credential Provider seem to change the Logon method not simply to add a button

Can someone highlight me ? Point me to an article or an example ?

Thanks a lot

Ps : i checked this article [C++ Windows Credential Provider Progress Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935430/c-windows-credential-provider-progress-screen) but it seem really to chaneg the whole Login Screen i just want to add a button on the bottom right next to the windows existing button for Wifi, UI customisation , Language